# Does Keras masking impact weight updates and loss calcuations?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mask

I'm working with time series, and understand that `keras.layers.Masking` and `keras.layers.Embedding` are useful to create a `mask` value in the network which indicates timesteps to 'skip'. The `mask` value is propagated throughout the network to be used by any layers that support it.

The [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/guides/understanding_masking_and_padding/) doesn't specify any further impacts of the `mask` value. My expectation is that the mask would be applied through all functions in model training and evaluation, but I don't see any evidence in support of this.

1. Does the `mask` value impact back-propagation?
2. Does the `mask` value impact the loss function or the metrics?
3. Would it be wise or foolish to use the `sample_weight` parameter in `model.compile()` to tell Keras to 'ignore' the masked timesteps in the loss function?

Answer (score 1):

I've performed some experiments to answer these questions.

Here's my sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np
# Fix the random seed for repeatable results
np.random.seed(5)
tf.random.set_seed(5)

x = np.array([[[3, 0], [1, 4], [3, 2], [4, 0], [4, 5]],
              [[1, 2], [3, 1], [1, 3], [5, 1], [3, 5]]], dtype='float64')

# Choose some values to be masked out
mask = np.array([[False, False,  True,  True,  True],
                 [ True,  True, False, False,  True]]) # True:keep.   False:ignore

samples, timesteps, features_in = x.shape
features_out = 1

y_true = np.random.rand(samples, timesteps, features_out)
# y_true[~mask] = 1e6 # TEST MODIFICATION

# Apply the mask to x
mask_value = 0 # Set to any value
x[~mask] = [mask_value] * features_in

input_tensor = keras.Input(shape=(timesteps, features_in))
this_layer = input_tensor
this_layer = keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=mask_value)(this_layer)
this_layer = keras.layers.Dense(10)(this_layer)
this_layer = keras.layers.Dense(features_out)(this_layer)

model = keras.Model(input_tensor, this_layer)
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x=x, y=y_true, epochs=100, verbose=0)

y_pred = model.predict(x)
print("y_pred = ")
print(y_pred)

print("model weights = ")
print(model.get_weights()[1])

print(f"{'model.evaluate':>14s} = {model.evaluate(x, y_true, verbose=0):.5f}")

# See if the loss computed by model.evaluate() is equal to the masked loss
error = y_true - y_pred
masked_loss = np.abs(error[mask]).mean()
unmasked_loss = np.abs(error).mean()
print(f"{'masked loss':>14s} = {masked_loss:.5f}")
print(f"{'unmasked loss':>14s} = {unmasked_loss:.5f}")
```

Which outputs

```
y_pred = 
[[[-0.28896046]
  [-0.28896046]
  [ 0.1546848 ]
  [-1.1596009 ]
  [ 1.5819632 ]]

 [[ 0.59000516]
  [-0.39362794]
  [-0.28896046]
  [-0.28896046]
  [ 1.7996234 ]]]
model weights = 
[-0.06686568  0.06484845 -0.06918766  0.06470951  0.06396528  0.06470013
  0.06247645 -0.06492618 -0.06262784 -0.06445726]
model.evaluate = 0.60170
   masked loss = 1.00283
 unmasked loss = 0.90808
```

#### mask and loss calculation

Surprisingly, the 'mae' (mean absolute error) loss calculation does NOT exclude the masked timesteps from the calculation. Instead, it assumes that these timesteps have zero loss - a perfect prediction. Therefore, **every masked timestep actually reduces the calculated loss!**
To explain in more detail: the above sample code input `x` has 10 timesteps. 4 of them are removed by the mask, so 6 valid timesteps remain. The 'mean absolute error' loss calculation sums the losses for the 6 valid timesteps, then divides by *10* instead of dividing by *6*. This looks like a bug to me.

#### output values are masked

Output values of masked timesteps do not impact the model training or evaluation (as it should be).
This can be easily tested by setting:
`y_true[~mask] = 1e6`
The model weights, predictions and losses remain exactly the same.

#### input values are masked

Input values of masked timesteps do not impact the model training or evaluation (as it should be).
Similarly, I can change `mask_value` from 0 to any other number, and the resulting model weights, predictions, and losses remain exactly the same.

#### In summary:

Q1: Effectively yes - the mask impacts the loss function, which is used through backpropagation to update the weights.
Q2: Yes, but the mask impacts the loss in an unexpected way.
Q3: Initially foolish - the mask should already be applied to the loss calculation. However, perhaps `sample_weights` could be valuable to correct the unexpected method of the loss calculation...

Note that I'm using Tensorflow 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling through this on a related issue, namely implementing a mask to a multi-output model where some samples are missing labels for different outputs.  Here, construct features, labels, sample_weights from a dataset and labels and sample_weights are dictionaries with equivalent keys.  The weights are 0,1 for each sample indicating if it should contribute to the calculation for the relevant loss.

I had hoped that sample_weights would contribute to the loss as they do when I pass the metric equivalents for the losses via weight_metrics in model.compile

I've found that sample_weight does not seem to address this problem.  I can tell from the training metrics that the task_loss values are different from task_metric values when sample weights are used.

I've given up on this and decided to go ahead and use masking.  The masked loss values are low in your case (and in mine) because tensorflow sees the modeled output as perfection - I hope this means it does not see a gradient for this points and so parameters aren't tuned in response.